# Create XML files on post edit screen

Tags: custom-post-types, xml

Ok, that's a weird question, I know..

I'm so confortable with WP that I don't want to use any other application to generate XML (KML - *Editors note: These are Google Earth files.*) files.

I want to use a custom post type with nothing else just a bunch of custom fields and meta boxes.
I have the XML schema (a custom single.php) set up: certain custom field values goes in between the right XML tags and in theory I have an XML that I'm able to create, modify and delete with WP.

The problem is that it is still a php/html file and not an xml, and the browser uses it as a html/php file and tries to interpret it as html even though xml is declared at the top.

Is there a libary or a way to grab the html output of these files and somehow convert it to XML?

Thanks.

**UPDATE 1:** That's how I get a placemark's name (it gives you the name) but without the  tags:

```
<?php if(get_field('marker_style')): ?>
    <?php while(the_repeater_field('marker_style')): ?>
        <?php echo '<name>' the_sub_field('marker_style_id') '</name>' ;?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Update 2**: With the help a tutorial I came up with this code: http://pastebin.com/zGJHm19t

But it's not working. It looks that I can't store my field values in variables and use them on the page in this context. You may think it's because of the plugin I use for custom fields, but that's not the case: if I put a simple `$title = the_title()` and then I try to echo the `$title` I get nothing.

On line 39-42 the original tutorial gave the values themselves and the XML got populated with them beautifully. The logic here is that I store the values in variables and use the vars here, but as I mentioned, for some reason I don't see right now, the variables are empty.

Comment: You should really show some code. Hard to tell anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using XML to send Ajax requests, then WP has something built in:

```
$response = new WP_Ajax_Response();
$response->add( array( 
     // This is the parent elements name
     'what' => 'xml_parent_el'
     // 'data' can only pass CDATA
    ,'data' => $foo
     // 'supplemental' can only pass elements with a unique name
    ,'supplemental' => $bar
) );
$response->send();
```

*If it's about ajax calls, go with JSON.*

The problem with this - due to the internal architecture of wp xml ajax - is that you **can't** send multiple elements with the same name. Wordpress needs an associative array, where keys are the elements name and values are ... well the values. So naming those elements keys exactly the same would override the previous element.

```
<xml_parent_el>
    <single_el attr="whatever a">Value A</single_el>
    <single_el attr="whatever b">Value B</single_el>
    <single_el attr="whatever c">Value C</single_el>
</xml_parent_el>
```

Your best bet in this case is using the [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/manual/de/book.simplexml.php) class provided by php.

---

**EDIT:** After seeing the paste, here's the corrected version. Misstypings can be in there.

```
<?php
$placemarks = Array();

$kml_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=kml' );
while ( $kml_query->have_posts() )
{
    $kml_query->the_post();
    if( get_field('marker_datas') )
    {
        while( the_repeater_field('marker_datas') ) 
        {
            $placemarks[ the_sub_field_return('placemark_name') ] = array(
                 'description'  => the_sub_field_return( 'placemark_text' )
                ,'styleUrl'     => the_sub_field_return( 'placemark_style_id' )
                ,'coordinates'  => the_sub_field_return( 'placemark_coordinates' )
            );
        }
    }
}

// Document
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();

// Root element
$root = $xmlDoc->appendChild( $xmlDoc->createElement("Document") );

foreach( $placemarks as $name => $data )
{
    // Tag
    $markerTag = $root->appendChild( $xmlDoc->createElement("Placemark") );

    $markerTag->appendChild( $xmlDoc->createElement( "Name", $name ) );

    $markerTag->appendChild( $xmlDoc->createElement( "Description", $data['description'] ) );

    $markerTag->appendChild( $xmlDoc->createElement("styleUrl", $data['styleUrl'] ) );

    // Coordinates
    $coordTag = $markerTag->appendChild( $xmlDoc->createElement( "Point" ) );
    $coordTag->appendChild( $xmlDoc->createElement( "coordinates", $data['coordinates'] ) );
}

header("Content-Type: text/plain");

// make the output pretty (later)
# $xmlDoc->formatOutput = true;

echo $xmlDoc->saveXML();
```

**EDIT:** The above snippet works just as expected. I was using the [repeater function](http://plugins.elliotcondon.com/advanced-custom-fields/documentation/the_repeater_field/) of the plugin called Advanced Custom Fields and since it echoes the field's values, a new function had to be added to the plugin which instead of echoing the values, simply returns them:

```
function the_sub_field_return($field_name, $field = false)
{
$value = get_sub_field($field_name, $field);
if(is_array($value))
{
    $value = implode(', ',$value);
}
return $value;
}
```

If you are happen to use the same plugin for a similar project don't forget to add the above function to api.php file located in the plugin's directory.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just experiencing right now, my code looks a bit messy. I'm using ACF's repeater field to be able to create multiple placemarks and so on... But actually I don't know what to except as the result, when I look the preview in the browser only the values are shown, the xml nametags are not.. is this normal?

Comment: Mate! Honestly: Should I know guess what _AFC's repeater field_ is? Show your code, link your plugins, etc.

Comment: [link](http://plugins.elliotcondon.com/shop/) Sorry.

Comment: N/P. The real problem is that I can't view any code as it's a paid plugin. So... what now?

Comment: Sorry Kaiser, guess my question was a bit reckless. I always edited KMLs in a text-editor, and honestly have know idea how to write xml files with php. At first I thought I just echo the values between the tags and that's it, apparently this is not that simple... I think the first step is to finish the page where I output the values and then somehow I convert that page to XML, would it be the correct way?

Comment: Good Q. I'd say it's enough if you echo stuff. You can also use a bla.xml.php and use this as xml files, but whithout any code i can't say anything.

Comment: I updated my original question with a snippet, pls have a look.

Comment: See Edit of your paste. _Should_ work. You have to check it on your own as I don't have your field functions and DB.

Comment: BTW: You **should** look at [this](http://code.google.com/intl/es/apis/kml/articles/phpmysqlkml.html) on how to create your output structure.

Comment: Thx for still being around. I actually don't know how to see the edits of my paste. Created an account and pasted it again: [http://pastebin.com/B6KTtuht](http://pastebin.com/B6KTtuht) I Found the same google tuto after started this conversation, I think I'm still trying to do it the hard way with WP.

Comment: I edited the answer... and as my answer states: There's **no** way to build this with wp onboard stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Using your code, the XML tree is built, the datas from the fields are called - only their values are at the top of the page, while the XMl nodes under are empty.

Comment: Could it be that your `*_field_*();` functions `echo` the output?

Comment: Well, yeah it could be, I'll look into its documentation. Would you like to see the `field()` function's code?

Comment: Yeah, the field function echoes those lines. Does that mean, that 1. either calling the fields could only happen after foreach, 2. this plugin is simply cannot be used for something like this?

Comment: You have to use the function behind your field functions. As soon as you call them, they echo. So you need to find a way around echoing the output of those fields. If they are no "wrapper" around another function, then copy/paste & rename them somewhere and remove the echo. Then everything should be fine. Btw: As we're far outside the focus of the orig. Q, it would be highly appreciated to upvote & mark this as solution. You should also edit my answer to reflect our discussion here in the comments so later readers get the point.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out Kaiser. I've found the solution and will edit your answer shortly. Thx.